# Logback Configuration Error in Tomcat 7

Tags: configuration, tomcat7, logback

I would like to use logback 1.0.0 to the activity of my web applications. Unfortunately the documentation on this subject is a tad sparse. I followed the official tutorial here:

http://logback.qos.ch/access.html

which involves using logback-access. I followed the instructions, yet when I direct my browser to /mywebapp/lbAccessStatus I got a class def not found error. Apparently it can not find the logback-accesss-1.0.0.jar that I have put in TOMCAT_HOME/lib . Has anyone else experienced this issue after the following the tutorial, or have any other tutorials available that describe alternate methods of logback configuration? I do not mind if each web app has their own log file, or just one global one I would just like to see the package work. Thank you for your help.